# Unable to generate class from xsd. Undefined complexType is used as a base for complex type extension

Tags: xml, class, xsd

I am trying to generate a class from xsd mentioned below but I am getting the following exception :

Undefined complexType 'http://ws.orbitz.com/schemas/v3/Hotel:BasicStayDetails' is used as a base for complex type extension.

Xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="http://ws.orbitz.com/schemas/v3/Hotel"
            xmlns:com="http://ws.orbitz.com/schemas/v3/Common"
            xmlns="http://ws.orbitz.com/schemas/v3/Hotel">

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="hotel_common.xsd"/>

    <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.orbitz.com/schemas/v3/Common" schemaLocation="../common/common.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="HotelShoppingResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:extension base="com:CommonResponseValues">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="PaginationKey" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xsd:annotation>
                                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                                    Key to identify multiple hotel search requests performed for pagination. This key
                                    will be used for tracking the client sessions for the same search criteria on
                                    Pagination.
                                </xsd:documentation>
                            </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="Location" type="com:Location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <xsd:element name="StayDetails" type="ShopStayDetails" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <xsd:element name="Hotels" type="Hotels" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <xsd:element name="Areas" type="com:Areas" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="ShopStayDetails">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="BasicStayDetails"/>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Hotels">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Hotel" type="ShopHotel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="href" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="hasMoreHotels" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="responseCount" type="com:Number" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="totalCount" type="com:Number" use="required">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    This attribute reflects all the hotels that matches the search criteria
                    regardless of availability.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ShopHotel">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Details" type="ShopDetails" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="Rooms" type="ShopRooms" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ShopDetails">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="BasicDetails">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Areas" type="com:NeighborhoodAreas" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Optional element - Contains list of neighborhood location
                                ids.
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="availability" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Optional element to distinguish the availability status of a
                            hotel as Available or Unknown.
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ShopRooms">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="BasicRooms">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="RoomRates" type="RoomRates" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the definition for: <xsd:complexType name="ShopStayDetails">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="BasicStayDetails"/>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
Unless it can look up that BasicStayDetails it will be unknown.

Comment: Jonatan : It is big , I cannot paste it.
please suggest.

Comment: I would open the XSD in for example Altova XMLSpy and see if there are some problems looking up parts of the imports. If it is that needs to be fixed before generating the class. What tool are you trying to use to generate the class?

Comment: Is defined into `hotel_common.xsd` the `complexType` `BasicStayDetails`? This error happen when missing the reference of an `XSD` (include or import), or when missing a definition of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the path of

```
schemaLocation="../common/common.xsd"/>
```

and add the missing xsd.
From Visual studio :

1. Add xsd in solution explorer.
2. Right click on root xsd and click on generate xml
3. Convert xml to class.